# Jump to the end of a long list of repeated pattern

Tags: vim

I have a big file with a lot of lines that share the same pattern, something like this:

```
dbn.py:206 ... (some other text)  <-- I am here
dbn.py:206 ... (some other text)
...
(something I don't know)          <-- I want to jump here
```

Is there a quick way in Vim to jump to the place where the succession of `dbp.py:206` ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>/</kbd>`^\(dbn.py\)\@!`

Matches first line which does not start with the text inside the escaped parentheses.

If you want quick access to this you could add a `vmap` which yanks the visually selected text and inserts it in the right spot (but first escaping it with `escape(var, '/')`.

Try this vmap: `vmap <leader>n "hy<Esc>/^\(<C-R>=escape(@h,'/')<CR>\)\@!<CR>`
Press n when visually selecting the text you wish to skip and you should be placed on the next first line which does not begin with the selection.

Comment: Nice use of negative lookahead. I couldn't get it to work in my testing because I didn't account for the preceding spaces in my matching line, so be careful there.

Answer (score 1):

I just write a function to select identical lines:

```
nnoremap vii :call SelectIdenticalLines()<CR>
fun! SelectIdenticalLines()
    let s = getline('.')
    let n = line('.')
    let i = n
    let j = n
    while getline(i)==s && i>0
        let i-=1
    endwhile

    while getline(j)==s && j<=line('$')
        let j+=1
    endwhile

    call cursor(i+1, 0)
    norm V
    call cursor(j-1, 0)
endfun
```

---

- type <kbd>vii</kbd> to select identical lines (feel free to change the key-binding)
- type <kbd>zf</kbd> to fold them.
- type <kbd>za</kbd> to toggle folding

---

It's handy when you want to squeeze several empty line.
It acts like <kbd>C-x C-o</kbd> in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go to the bottom of the file and search backwards for the last line you want, then go down one:

<kbd>G</kbd> `?^dbn\.py:206?+1`

Comment: Not if the pattern keeps repeating in several blocks.